# Splitting DEM at certain elevation?

Tags: gdal, dem, geotiff-tiff

I have a DEM that includes bathymetry and terrain elevation and I would like to split it at the coastline. Ideally, I would end up with one tif that's land and one tif that's bathymetry.

I have searched for this feature in GDAL commands and in QGIS but I can't find anything that extracts based on an elevation range.

Comment: do you have any python experience? this is a very simple task if you create two identical dimension rasters and copy the values to one if <= 0 and the other if >= 0. I can't see a tool for it straight away in GDAL, if you have access to ESRI you would be wanting extract by attributes (geoprocessing tool)

Comment: Thank you! I think I know enough python to figure this out.

Comment: Awesome! It should be fairly straightforward but if you run into any difficulties there are plenty of 'GDAL in python' posts to help you through the bumpy bits. It's a bit of a shame that there's not an off-the-shelf solution for this, it seems like something that would be required occasionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can make two rasters on the same extent, one with height and the other with bathymetry, but rasters are always rectangle so you will have a lot of "zeros". If you only use gdal tools, you could use [gdal_calc](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html), for example:

```
gdal_calc.py -A dem.tif --outfile=bathymetry.tif --calc="(A<=0)*A"

gdal_calc.py -A dem.tif --outfile=elevation.tif --calc="(A>=0)*A"
```

A<=0 will evaluate as 0 or 1.

Remark 1: Be careful that land surfaces are sometimes below the sea level, so a simple threshold is sometimes not sufficient.

Remark 2: I also suggest you to add '-co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES' as tif creation options.